Monospaced fonts and Aspect Ratio: Google vs. On-Screen measurements
On macOS Terminal (Sequoia, M4) I use the font Monaco and I like draw ASCII art, but it's always stretched vertically on the screen because the characters are narrower than they are tall.
I zoomed way in and used a transparent ruler to measure the letter "H", it was 11.5 cm high and 7 cm wide (arbitrary zoom level, it's the ratio that matters)
But if I google for it, about Monaco and Courier New, they keep claiming that they both have an aspect ratio close to 1.0; this just doesn't agree with what I'm seeing.
It would be NICE if all monospaced fonts were the same width and height, but that's not what monospaced means; it's just about the relative width of each letter to the other, it says nothing about height nor aspect ratio as I understand it.

What is your question?

Sure: Why does the internet claim that fonts like Courier New and Monaco 1:1 fonts, but when I measure them, they're clearly not.  There must be some explanation for this discrepancy.  Is there some technical difference that makes them behave one way on the screen, and maybe differently on paper?  Or different fonts with the same name?  Has anyone else noticed this?  Or asked about it?  (I haven't found on Google)

Sorry, but there is no answer to this question. Whoever claimed monospaced fonts have uniform metrics/dimensions was plain wrong. Fonts have never been standardized by any means: captital letter heights vary same applies to descenders (e.g lowercase "g" going below the baseline). Also, there are hinting instruction which may also adjust the rendered width or height for the sake of a crisper rendering. You can't provide a consistent perfectly predictible rendering in console output. For web application you could load a custom font with the desired width
